# insert radiobox in menu in forms

Tags: winforms, radio-button, menuitem

How can I insert radiobutton in Menu as Menu item. I use WinForms and there I see only few option to insert other controls, but no radio :/
 Also it's impossible to drag it from Controls and drop in menu in Design View :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because an actual "radio button" control as a menu item would be weird, when you can already show a menu item as "checked" using the "radio button style". See the MenuItem.RadioCheck property.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do want to do this, create an owner drawn menu. This is pretty straightforward. Here's a tutorial:

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/ownerdraw-menu-items-in-c/

As for drawing the radiobuttons, use the static functions of the ControlPaint class.